Why is indexOf returning zero if used with json.decode
In flutter, I have this code that returns zero for all item2:
for (var item2 in json.decode(item.details?["result"]))
   Text(
     ((json.decode(item.details?["result"])).indexOf(item2) + 1).toString()
   ),

My question is why does the above code output 0, while the below code shows the correct index:
for (var item in values)
   Text(
     (values.indexOf(item) + 1).toString()
   ),

UPDATE: My actual code is below, so I cannot really declare a new variable inside the for loop...or can I?
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
         ...
         for (var item in values)
            Text(
               (values.indexOf(item) + 1).toString()
            ),
            for (var item2 in json.decode(item.details?["result"]))
               Text(
                  ((json.decode(item.details?["result"])).indexOf(item2) + 1).toString()
               ),
      ),
   );
}


You can declare a new variable to hold the decoded result outside the loop. This avoids repeatedly decoding the same JSON string and ensures consistent behavior. Here's how:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          for (var item in values)
            Text(
              (values.indexOf(item) + 1).toString(),
            ),
          for (var item in values)
            ...(() {
              // Decode once and reuse the result
              final decodedResult = json.decode(item.details?["result"]) as List;
              return decodedResult.map((item2) {
                return Text(
                  (decodedResult.indexOf(item2) + 1).toString(),
                );
              });
            })(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}


Can you explain this part ...(() { please? Why they three dots?

The spread operator in Flutter is used inside a Column, Row, or other widget lists to insert multiple widgets into the widget tree.
It "spreads" the elements of an iterable (like a List or Iterable) into the list of children.

The issue arises because json.decode generates new objects each time it's called, and indexOf in Dart compares objects by reference for complex types like lists, maps, or other objects
regrading the loop in the widget tree there is another way ,
class ExampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ExampleWidget({super.key});

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> values = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: values.map((e) => Text(e["your property"].toString())).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Thanks, I came to similar conclusion myself, the details you provide explain what happens very well. I've updated my question, may I ask you to check / suggest a solution  if possible?
